# Jackson Mixin not working for deserializing non-default constructor object

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, mixins

I am writing a mixin to deserialize a string into javax.servlet.http.Cookie

`Mixin.java`

```
package a;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public abstract class MixIn {
      MixIn(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") String value) { }

}
```

`HelloWorld.java`

```
package b;

import a.MixIn;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Cookie.class, MixIn.class);
Cookie aCookie = mapper.readValue("{"name":"abc","value":"xyz"}", Cookie.class);
```

It seems to provide "JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class javax.servlet.http.Cookie]" error.

Please do note that

- Mixin is (has to be) defined as a separate class (NOT an inner class, not static)

- Mixin and the class where its used are (have to be) in 2 different packages.

I am using jackson 1.9.9

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce. Here is the link to my code: https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/stackoverflow/tree/master/src/main/java/stackoverflow/mixin

Comment: Marked as a duplicate of a more recent question. The answer to both is in THIS question.

Answer (score 9):

Creating a separate class for the Mixin,

```
public abstract class MixinClass extends OriginalClass {

    //`datamember` is the datamember required to create instance of OriginalClass
    @JsonCreator
    MixinClass(@JsonProperty("item") datamember item) { super(item); }
}
```

In the mapper class add this,

```
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(OriginalClass.class, MixinClass.class);
```

This will resolve the issue. Make sure that the MixinClass is a separate .java file and not an inner class.

Comment: I am doing this exact thing and it doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me thank you.

Comment: mixin could be in the same file, provided it is static

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to include @JsonCreator over the mixin constructor? I'm still struggling with a similar issue myself, so I'm not 100% certain here.

My question: [@JsonCreator and mixin via Module not working for 3rd Party Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650678/jsoncreator-and-mixin-via-module-not-working-for-3rd-party-class)

Update: my example in the above question is working, your comment on the mixin needing to be in a separate package and not an inner class did the trick, thanks!