# Jackson Mixin + creator not working

Tags: java, jackson

I need to override/fix the serialization mechanism for a 3rd party class (google maps classes) so that I can marshal the objects in from a file on disk. I have seen [several examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795488/jackson-mixin-not-working-for-deserializing-non-default-constructor-object) of what I am trying to do and none of them seems to work.

The troubled class:

```
public class LatLng implements UrlValue {
    public double lat;
    public double lng;

    public LatLng(double lat, double lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

My mixin

```
public abstract class LatLnMixIn {
    @JsonCreator
    public LatLnMixIn(@JsonProperty("lat") Double lat, @JsonProperty("lng ")Double lng) {}
}
```

My usage

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().addMixIn(LatLng.class, LatLnMixIn.class);
    InputStream mockStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mz-to-nordstrom-rack-snoq.json");
    DirectionsResult mockResult = mapper.readValue(mockStream, DirectionsResult.class);
```

snippet of the json to be marshaled:

```
      "start_location" : {
        "lat" : 47.5985728,
        "lng" : -122.3315845
      },
```

My error (with/without mixin)

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable
>   constructor found for type [simple type, class
>   com.google.maps.model.LatLng]: can not instantiate from JSON object
>   (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable
>   type information?)

Does anyone see where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: The `Double` vs `double` makes all the difference. Just make them `double` parameters in the mixin class constructor.

Comment: Also, the `@JsonCreator` should not be necessary.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis turn your comment into an answer to get credit. That's the trip. Honestly, this class structure from google is so unfriendly that I think I might just marshal it all in as a map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixins work with matching constructor and method signatures. Your target class constructor looks like

```
public LatLng(double lat, double lng)
```

while your mixin constructor is defined as

```
public LatLnMixIn(Double lat, Double lng)
```

Jackson considers `double` and `Double` as different types and therefore doesn't find a matching constructor in the target class.

Simply change your constructor to use `double` parameters.

---

The `@JsonCreator` annotation is unnecessary in this specific example.